# how to read number list from docx (word file)

Tags: python, xml, ms-word

**how to read  number list from docx (word file)**

**bulletsquestions.docx:**

```
  1. this is a question text 
    A.  Option first
    B.  Option second
    C.  Option third
    D.  Option fourth
    E.  Option fifth
```

**stack.py:**

```
 import zipfile
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XML
sourceFile = zipfile.ZipFile('bulletsquestions.docx')
xml_content = sourceFile.read('word/document.xml')
WORD_NAMESPACE = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}'
PARA = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'p'
TEXT = WORD_NAMESPACE + 't'
tree = XML(xml_content)
tex=""
for paragraph in tree.getiterator(PARA):
    for read_item in paragraph.getiterator(TEXT):
        tex=tex+read_item.text
print(tex)
```

**RESULT:**

1. this is a question text Option firstOption secondOption thirdOption fourthOption fifth

Comment: You should explain what the output should look like.

Comment: 1. myself Priyanshu jain A. Option firstB. Option secondC. Option thirdD. Option fourthE. Option fifth

Comment: @pjrocks sorry but I don't know the XML-schema for that.

Comment: can you print a sample xml of the file you extracted ?